# EKS 1.25 podsecurity policy changing

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

We currently are on EKS `1.22`, however with the updates to `1.25`, old security rules will be depreciated and the transition to Pod Security Admission will be enforced.

I am however, confused reading the updates whether the below code will still be fine. Currently we have a `kubernetes_job` defined in Terraform that has the below `security_context`:

```
security_context {
  run_as_non_root = true
  run_as_user = "1000"
  run_as_group = "2000"
  capabilities {
    drop = ["all"]
  }
  allow_privilege_escalation = false
}
```

Will this still work in `1.25`? Or will this have to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PodSecurityPolicy](https://v1-24.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/policy-resources/pod-security-policy-v1beta1/) was a separate API object.  The deprecation doesn't refer to the [security context in a PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#security-context), which you seem to be describing here in Terraform syntax; the PodSpec syntax is unchanged, including in Deployments and other higher-level objects.

Unless you're a cluster administrator or writing an operator that will be used principally by cluster administrators, the PodSecurityPolicy deprecation won't affect you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a PSS restricted namespace you will also need seccompProfile.type set to either RuntimeDefault or Localhost. If it is set to Localhost then other settings are required.